# Computer goes haywire when connected to modem/router or switch, but not AP

Tags: windows-7, networking, routing, switching

I've got a really weird situation with one workstation on my network.

Topology:

Comcast Business class modem/router -> D-Link gigabit switch (192.168.42.0/24) -> Linksys EA6500 router/AP (192.168.1.0/24)
DHCP/DNS handled by Win2k12 server

When I connect this Windows 7 Pro workstation directly to the Comcast router, Outlook goes berserk, constantly connecting and disconnecting from the Exchange server and yielding all sorts of errors about being unable to access other email accounts. Internet pages completely fail to load. The computer is sluggish and unusable. But all of these problems are intermittent.

When I connect the same workstation to the switch (still pulling from the *.42.0 pool) I have the same issues.

But when I connect the workstation to the AP (wired), it behaves itself...no problems.

Connectivity across all other workstations and wireless devices is fine.

What on earth could be causing a situation like this? I'm more than a bit stumped.

Comment: Is there some reason you have two LANs? It's a much more complex setup than you probably need or want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your comcast box is not bridged and handing out a different ip address range, or possibly handing you a duplicate address from its own pool. Make sure it is bridged and that DHCP is disabled.

Comment: Finally got back around to looking into this. Some rogue AP on the network was running in MAC clone mode and causing the conflict.